# PHP check value on external website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I can't seem to figure out:

How can I make my website look/check csgo.steamanalyst.com or steamcommunity.com/market market for Counter-Strike Global Offensive skin prices?

I have made so people can log onto my webpage and I got all information of the logged in user, except the password ofc. I'm making a CSGO betting website. I have everything made, I just need some kind of script, that checks what the skins are worth on steamcommunity or steamanalyst.

- Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could scrape those websites but I recommend using an API if possible.

Comment: There must be some kind of API to that.